# Removing text from RichTextBox is not working

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am trying to remove characters from current cursor position to start of the string. It's working fine in simple TextBox

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
            {
                int LineNumber = txtDescription___.GetLineFromCharIndex(txtDescription___.SelectionStart);
                txtDescription___.Text = txtDescription___.Text.Remove(0, txtDescription___.SelectionStart - 0);
            }
```

But when I am trying to execute this code with `RichTextBox` it works on Text not on RTF and removes all styles. So I tried this code

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
            {
                int LineNumber = txtDescription___.GetLineFromCharIndex(txtDescription___.SelectionStart);
                txtDescription___.Rtf = txtDescription___.Rtf.Remove(0, txtDescription___.SelectionStart - 0);
            }
```

Now It's showing the following error
`File Format is not valid`
Can someone suggest me. How can I perform same code with RTF?

Comment: https://help.citavi.com/en/knowledge-base/article/error-file-format-is-not-valid

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do; what is *the start of the string*? Do you mean the start of the text or the current line? You have declared `int LineNumber`, but you're never using it. Maybe you wanted to call `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(LineNumber)` and use it as the `SelectionStart` value? -- Selections work on text, not on the underlying RTF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
{
    int began = rtbDescription___.SelectionStart;
    rtbDescription___.SelectionLength = began;
    rtbDescription___.SelectedText = "";
}
```

Comment: It's not the exact answer I was looking for. But it helped me. Thanks

Comment: can u please upvote